# T-SQL: query xml with namespace

Tags: xml, t-sql

I've done some basic xml work in T-SQL before, but literally 'basic'.

Now come across some more complex xml and I am completely flummoxed as to where to begin.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Calculation:scenario xmlns:Calculation="http://www.sap.com/ndb/BiModelCalculation.ecore" schemaVersion="2.3" id="ADR2" applyPrivilegeType="ANALYTIC_PRIVILEGE" checkAnalyticPrivileges="true" defaultClient="$$client$$" defaultLanguage="$$language$$" visibility="internal" calculationScenarioType="TREE_BASED" dataCategory="DIMENSION" enforceSqlExecution="false" executionSemantic="UNDEFINED" outputViewType="Projection">
<origin/>
<descriptions defaultDescription="ADR2"/>
<metadata activatedAt="2015-04-22 16:13:29.0" changedAt="2015-04-22 21:12:59.193"/>
<localVariables/>
<variableMappings/>
<dataSources>
    <DataSource id="ADR2" ....
```

All my attempts just bring back `<blank>`
I am guessing the issue is the semicolon "Calculation:scenario" and  "xmlns:Calculation"
From googling so far, this is a 'namespace'.

However, in all examples I have found of querying xml with namespaces, the source xml has a property such as : xmlns:ns="uri"

They then use this in the query :  ";WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri' as ns)"

My xml does not have this ns attribute.

Could anyone give me any pointers as to where to begin, or some basic tutorial that includes my scenario ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example to select an element or attribute in namespace :

```
declare @xml XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Calculation:scenario xmlns:Calculation="http://www.sap.com/ndb/BiModelCalculation.ecore" schemaVersion="2.3" id="ADR2" applyPrivilegeType="ANALYTIC_PRIVILEGE" checkAnalyticPrivileges="true" defaultClient="$$client$$" defaultLanguage="$$language$$" visibility="internal" calculationScenarioType="TREE_BASED" dataCategory="DIMENSION" enforceSqlExecution="false" executionSemantic="UNDEFINED" outputViewType="Projection">
<origin/>
<descriptions defaultDescription="ADR2"/>
<metadata activatedAt="2015-04-22 16:13:29.0" changedAt="2015-04-22 21:12:59.193"/>
<localVariables/>
<variableMappings/>
</Calculation:scenario>'

select @xml.value('declare namespace calc="http://www.sap.com/ndb/BiModelCalculation.ecore";
(calc:scenario/@id)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as 'scenario_id'
```

Output :

[image]

Basically you need to declare mapping of namespace prefix (`calc`) to namespace URI (`http://www.sap.com/ndb/BiModelCalculation.ecore`), then use the declared prefix properly in the XQuery statement (`(calc:scenario/@id)[1]`). All mentioned steps are demonstrated in the above example.

For reference :

- [MSDN: XML.value()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx)
- [MSDN: XML.nodes()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx)